# Room Persistence: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor

Tags: java, android, database

I am trying to add a database to my android app through the Room Persistence library and i am getting this error:

> error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can      have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
>       Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
>       User(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int,int,java.lang.String)     -> [param:id -> matched field:unmatched, param:name -> matched     field:unmatched, param:gender -> matched field:unmatched, param:age -> matched field:unmatched, param:weight -> matched field:unmatched, param:height -> matched field:unmatched, param:workout -> matched field:unmatched]

Here is my code:

```
    @Entity
    public class User {

@PrimaryKey
private int userId;
private String userName;
private String userGender;
private int userAge;
private int userWeight;
private int userHeight;
private String workoutPlan;


public User(int id, String name, String gender, int age, int weight, int height, String workout) {

    this.userId = id;
    this.userName = name;
    this.userGender = gender;
    this.userAge = age;
    this.userWeight = weight;
    this.userHeight = height;
    this.workoutPlan = workout;

} ...
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong or what i missed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please change names of the parameters such that it matches entity attributes.

```
  public User(int userId, String userName, String userGender, int userAge, int userWeight, int userHeight, String workoutPlan) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userGender = userGender;
    this.userAge = userAge;
    this.userWeight = userWeight;
    this.userHeight = userHeight;
    this.workoutPlan = workoutPlan;
  } ...
```

For persistance, it uses JavaBeans conventions in Room. For more information:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#java

Comment: Seems unnecessary for the parameter names to match the attribute names exactly--I've seen lots of other patterns and I think the one in the question is quite valid..  Do  you have a justification for this?

Comment: it's from the documentation that a constructor whose parameters contain types and names that match those of the fields in the entity. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Comment: @pradipforever Very interesting!  Thank you. This is something new... Generally the variable name information is thrown away and so it can't be relied on by libraries, apparently this is no longer true and some libraries are taking advantage of the fact already!  Learn something new every day.

Comment: yep, true, this library is taking advantage of variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin :

```
@Entity(tableName = "t_article_tabs")
data class WxArticleTabsEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tabId") @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id") val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tabName") @SerializedName("name") val name: String?,
    ...
    @Ignore  @SerializedName("children") val children: List<Any>?,
)
```

Change to :

```
@Entity(tableName = "t_article_tabs")
data class WxArticleTabsEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tabId") @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id") val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tabName") @SerializedName("name") val name: String?,
    ...
){
    @Ignore  @SerializedName("children") val children: List<Any>? = null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this:-

```
@Ignore
public User(int userId, String userName, String userGender, int userAge, int 
      userWeight, int userHeight, String workoutPlan ) {
   this.userId = userId;
   this.userName = userName;
   this.userGender = userGender;
   this.userAge = userAge;
   this.userWeight = userWeight;
   this.userHeight = userHeight;
   this.workoutPlan = workoutPlan;
 }

 public User(String userName, String userGender, int userAge, int 
      userWeight, int userHeight, String workoutPlan) {
   this.userName = userName;
   this.userGender = userGender;
   this.userAge = userAge;
   this.userWeight = userWeight;
   this.userHeight = userHeight;
   this.workoutPlan = workoutPlan;
 }
```

Comment: Working file..!

Answer (score 0):

I got around this same problem by just adding a empty constructor.
    `public User(){}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved problem just removing `@Ignore` from default constructor.

If you copied your code from some place, and have `@Ignore` in default constructor then need to remove `@Ignore` from default constructor.

**Before:**

```
@Ignore
public Card(){}
```

**After:**

```
public Card(){}
```

I just added because it's happen with me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. Only one of my attributes in my constructor did not match and I was finding it rather confusing. My variable (outside the constructor) was named mURL and I was trying to match it to url within the constructor.

Instead, I should have set the outer variable to mUrl. Yes, capitalising the last 2 letters gave me that error. Setting `this.mUrl = url` instead of `this.mURL = url` solved the error.