# Kotlin Room error : entities and pojos should have a constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Please do not mark this as a duplicate I have seen other similar posts but nothing helped

My entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "batch_table")
data class Batch(
    val batch_id: String? ="",
    val batch_name: String? ="",
    val user_m_id: String? ="",
    val user_profile_id: String? =""
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id1: Int? = 0
constructor():this("","","","")
}
```

My Dao :

```
@Dao
interface BatchDao{

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(batch : MutableList<Batch>)

    @Query("delete from batch_table")
    suspend fun deleteBatchTable()

    @Query(" select * from batch_table ")
    suspend fun getAllBatches() :List<Batch>

    @Query("select batch_name from batch_table where batch_id = :batch_id")
    suspend fun getBatchName(batch_id:String)

    @Transaction
    suspend fun insertBatches(batch: MutableList<Batch>){
        deleteBatchTable()
        insert(batch)
    }
```

I was using `room` and all I did was add the 4th function (getBatchName) in my `dao`, but I am not sure why this error started to occur.

The error during compilation:

```
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - `kotlin.Unit`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874559/room-persistence-entities-and-pojos-must-have-a-usable-public-constructor/53874729

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to write the return type of the function but the error that was thrown pointed me to a different thing so I got confused.

```
 @Query("select batch_name from batch_table where batch_id = :batch_id")
    suspend fun getBatchName(batch_id:String) : String
```

.